# How can I access elements of iframe loaded from other domain(FTP)

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to load html page from different domain using below code,

```
  var str = "http://***_Images/";
  $('body').append('<iframe id="iframe" style="position:fixed;' +
  + 'top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%" src="' 
  + str +   
  $('#htmNum').val() + '.html"></iframe>');
```

But when I am trying to access elements from that iframe using below code I am unable to access

```
  $('#iframe').contents().find('img').length // Returns me nothing
```

How can I do this. Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, due to security restrictions imposed by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only if the server of the other domain is cooperating by setting [access control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) putting your domain on a white list or allowing cross domain access from any domain.

Another solution involves an intermediate server (your server would be the simplest) acting as a proxy querying the other domain server to let the browser see only one domain.

Please note that the second solution might not be considered correct (or legal) by the other domain server owner. You should check this point.

Comment: Actually the file I am loading is from FTP.. Still it is not possible.. Please revert back

Comment: You put HTTP in your question ?

Comment: In the text of the question, the URL is in http. If the third party element you want to access is served in ftp, I suggest you to use the proxy solution.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do it.. I don't have an idea of that

Comment: You could either set a standard proxy server (google for the OS you use server side, this could be http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-proxy-server-ubuntu-linux/) or you can, in the server language you use (PHP ? Ruby ? Go ? JSP ?) query the other domain server and embedd the content of the pages in yours.